# Criar bat para finalizar Serviço

Tags: apache, windows, services

Estou tentando criar um arquivo .bat para finalizar e iniciar um serviço no Windows.

Para fazer isso eu primeiro finalizo o processo depois reinicio o serviço

Mas o comando dentro do arquivo em lote (.bat) não encontra o processo que é

```
taskkill /f /im httpdPHP5.exe
```

Mas se eu usar esse comando dentro do MS-DOS ele encontra o processo e finaliza

O comando completo para reiniciar o serviço é:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im httdPHP5.exe
net stop Apache2.4_PHP5
net start Apache2.4_PHP5
```

Segue imagem anexo de exemplo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou o **p** no **httpdPHP5** do .bat (está como **httdPHP5**)

Comment: na verdade o p rsrs, Mas obrigado.

Comment: Opa, bati o dedo errado rs.. 
Corrigido!

Comment: Fiquei ceguinho oh kkk